# How can I modify a button's background for state pressed?

Tags: android, styles, view

I'm building an accessibility app for people with bad eyesight where users can choose their own combination of colors. For this reason I need to change buttons' backgrounds programatically depending on their preferences.

I want to set the background color for when the button is not pressed and a different color for when it's pressed. However I doing setBackgroundColor overrides both values.

```
        ((Button) view).setBackgroundColor(customColor1);
```

How can I set customColor1 for when the button is not pressed and customColor2 for when it is?

Comment: you need a toggle button kind of thing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)));

btn.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```